# How to send some api call sequentially and some api calls parallely for the same user action

Tags: jmeter

How to send some api call sequentially and some api calls parallely for the same  user action .

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Parallel controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

I tried to simulate your scenario in this screenshot below
[image]

I added 2 `Debug Samplers` before `Parallel controller` and 2 after the controller. On the right hand side if you see `Debug Sampler 3` and `Debug Sampler 4` started at same time whereas others have a different start time indicating a sequential run.

Answer (score 0):

- For sending requests sequentially just add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, one per request and each JMeter thread (virtual user) will execute them upside down
- For sending requests in parallel put the relevant HTTP Request samplers under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)

[image]